# Ignore cascade on foreign key update?

Tags: mysql, database-design

To preface, I'm not very experienced with database design. I have a table of hashes and ids. When a group of new hashes are added, each row in the group gets the same id. If any hash within the new group already exists in the database, all hashes in the new group and existing group(s) get a new, shared id (effectively merging ids when hashes are repeated):

```
INSERT INTO hashes 
    (id, hash) 
VALUES 
    ($new_id, ...), ($new_id, ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    repeat_count = repeat_count + 1;

INSERT INTO hashes_lookup SELECT DISTINCT id FROM hashes WHERE hash IN (...);
UPDATE hashes JOIN hashes_lookup USING (id) SET id = '$new_id';
TRUNCATE TABLE hashes_lookup;
```

Other tables reference these ids, so that if an id changes, foreign key constraints take care of updating the ids across tables. The issue here, however, is that I can't enforce uniqueness across any of the child tables. If I do, my queries fail with:

> Foreign key constraint for table '...', record '...' would lead to a duplicate entry in table '...'

This error makes sense, given the following test case where `id` and `value` are a composite unique key:

```
id | value
---+-------
a  | 1
b  | 2
c  | 1
```

Then `a` gets changed to `c`:

```
id | value
---+-------
c  | 1
b  | 2
c  | 1
```

But `c,1` already exists.

It would be ideal if there was an `ON UPDATE IGNORE CASCADE` option, so that if a duplicate row exists, any duplicating inserts are ignored. However, I'm pretty sure the real issue here is my database design, so I am open to any and all suggestions. My current solution is to not enforce uniqueness across child tables, which leads to a lot of redundant rows.

Edit:

```
CREATE TABLE `hashes` (
 `hash` char(64) NOT NULL,
 `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `repeat_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `insert_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `update_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 UNIQUE KEY `hash` (`hash`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `emails` (
 `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `group_id` char(5) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 KEY `index` (`id`) USING BTREE,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`group_id`,`email`(255)) USING BTREE,
 CONSTRAINT `emails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `hashes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Please show the definition of the tables.

Comment: I would ditch the update cascade and manually do that part. To me that concept is always playing with fire.

Comment: @Renzo Updated with the hashes table an example child table, in this case a table holding emails.

Comment: @Drew Yeah, I'm starting to see it that way as well. I could keep the foreign key for delete purposes, correct?

Comment: I love delete cascades. Thx for saving me the effort. But for exactly your op question, the update cascades are a problem. Unless your delete cascades are problematic,keep them.

Comment: So as dumb as it sounds, you could do this. Have 3rd column called something like `updtCount`, an int. You probably see where this one is going. Use that for an IODKU so you technically have something to update with a +1. The reason for that is many software camps are not too keen on `insert ignore`. You can get around that with the IODKU. Make them think you have some real special reason for caring to increment that thing :p .... Then do the *other* update. Then do the delete.

Comment: In a good database design foreign keys should reference primary keys. So I would suggest that you alter your structure. You can always create views to bring values together. The naming of fields could be improved: as *hash* is  the primary key, it is really confusing that you have another field in the same table called *id*. You really should consider renaming *id* to *groupid*, and *hash* to *id*, and then let the foreign key in *emails* point to that *id* (so what previously was *hash*). That would need of course a one-shot bulk update in *emails*

Comment: @trincot Do you have any suggestions on how I could alter the table efficiently? And yes, good point on naming.

Comment: @Drew Haha that seems to make my database design even more complex! I appreciate the suggestion though, but I think I should focus on simplifying everything :D

Comment: I don't really understand the id and hash columns based on your original version 1 of the question. But, `insert ignore` is frowned upon. That said, I love it. I just don't go around recommending it too much. The reason for it is to avoid seeing pre-existence prior.

Comment: @trincot Can you elaborate/explain your suggestion in an answer? Or walk me through it on chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117832/on-update-ignore-cascade

Comment: What if two of the new hashes exist in the table, but with _different_ ids?

Comment: @RickJames That's taken care of by the `hashes_lookup` table and subsequent UPDATE. Essentially, all existing ids are changed to a single id if any overlap occurs over 1+ ids. You can see what I mean in my code example, let me know if doesn't make sense though.

Comment: Could you explain your design/concept? Usually, if you reach such conceptional difficulties in relational databases (your problem is not something just limited mysql can't do), you are doing something wrong. Maybe it's just me, but I have a hard time understanding the idea behind it - it feels a bit like some kind of strange duplicate (check or management) system. E.g., what happens if you have an entry in email for id = 1 and one for id = 2; then you add hashes and detect that 1 and 2 have to be new group 3 - what SHOULD happen to those entries in emails (they can't be both 3, id is the pk).

Comment: @Solarflare Your interpretation is correct. What should happen is if they have the same PK, then the "duplicate" (either of the two) should be removed.

Comment: I guess, technically, you COULD achieve what you are trying by adding another table `ids` with every id once in it, and link all child tables except hashes to this table. When you want to merge groups 1 2 and 3 to new group 4: in ids: update 3->4; in hashes: update 1,2,3->4; in ids: delete 1,2. But I would strongly advise you to redesign your datamodel, you are stretching the idea of primary keys and cascades beyond their purpose (they are not to be merged, just renamed, they are primary keys for a reason). There are better ways to manage duplicates (usually by keeping both, marking 1 main).

Comment: @Solarflare I'm honestly not married to the current implementation, so if you have any database redesign suggestions I'm all ears! I think you understand what I want to do, but if not I can explain better in chat.

Comment: Can I ask why are you changing the ids? what is the purpose of having that key? Why don't you just add a column `hash` and reference it to the `hash` column in table `hashes`?

Comment: Because many hashes belong to one id, and when new hashes are duplicates of existing hashes, all old ids change to a new id to unify all the hashes.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what you are trying to do, thats why I asked for your concept (e.g. if managing the duplicates is the whole point of your whole database, or if your logic is an addon to a db with another purpose, e.g. a customer db). Modelling the db to fit your requirements is actually an (or the) important (and expensive) step in your development process, so I don't know exactly how your model should look like without more information. Just some general ideas: a) Do not change the primary keys. b) Use the hastable as a helpertable (without links) and do your logic (e.g. deletion

Comment: of the duplicates) in a procedure (at least one "main" one, the rest can be cascades). This way is MUCH clearer, MUCH simpler, usually describes the logic best, and you have much more options to process your data. Don't force your logic into cascades. c) If you want to keep your duplicates (depending on the purpose of the database, in most business requirements you want and need to keep both), you can e.g use markers, a duptable (e.g. (id, idmain)), or, as a last option, some kind of archive.

Comment: @Solarflare Can we discuss this on chat (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117832/on-update-ignore-cascade)? You make very valid points but I want to fully understand/explain what I'm trying to do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, which we have arrived in chat [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117832/on-update-ignore-cascade):

```
/* Tables */

CREATE TABLE `emails` (
 `group_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `group_id` (`group_id`,`email`) USING BTREE,
 CONSTRAINT `emails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `entities` (`group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `hashes` (
 `group_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `hash` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `repeat_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 UNIQUE KEY `hash` (`hash`),
 KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `hashes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `entities` (`group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `entities` (
 `group_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `entity_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),
 KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `entity_lookup` (
 `entity_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`) USING HASH
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

/* Inserting */

START TRANSACTION;

/* Determine next group ID */
SET @next_group_id = (SELECT MAX(group_id) + 1 FROM entities);

/* Determine next entity ID */
SET @next_entity_id = (SELECT MAX(entity_id) + 1 FROM entities);

/* Merge any entity ids */
INSERT IGNORE INTO entity_lookup SELECT entity_id FROM entities JOIN hashes USING(group_id) WHERE HASH IN(...);
UPDATE entities JOIN entity_lookup USING(entity_id) SET entity_id = @next_entity_id;
TRUNCATE TABLE entity_lookup;

/* Add the new group ID to entity_id */
INSERT INTO entities(group_id, entity_id) VALUES(@next_group_id, @next_entity_id);

/* Add new values into hashes */
INSERT INTO hashes (group_id, HASH) VALUES 
    (@next_group_id, ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  repeat_count = repeat_count + 1;

/* Add other new values */
INSERT IGNORE INTO emails (group_id, email) VALUES
    (@next_group_id, "email1");
    
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think will be good to create table `hash_group` to store id of hash group:

```
CREATE TABLE `hash_group` (
 `id` BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 `group_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `insert_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `update_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 UNIQUE KEY `group_name` (`group_name`) USING BTREE,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And change structure of existing tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `hashes` (
 `hash` char(64) NOT NULL,
 `hash_group_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
 `repeat_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `insert_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `update_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 UNIQUE KEY `hash` (`hash`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `hashes_hash_group_id_index` (`hash_group_id`) USING BTREE,
 CONSTRAINT `hashes_hash_group_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`hash_group_id`) REFERENCES `hash_group` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `emails` (
 `hash_group_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
 `group_id` char(5) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 KEY `emails_hash_group_id_index` (`hash_group_id`) USING BTREE,
 UNIQUE KEY `emails_unique` (`hash_group_id`,`group_id`,`email`(255)) USING BTREE,
 CONSTRAINT `emails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`hash_group_id`) REFERENCES `hash_group` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Also create trigger to update hash group if you need to do it:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `update_hash_group_name` AFTER UPDATE ON `hashes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `hash_group` 
    SET `group_name` = md5(now()) -- replace to you hash formula
    WHERE id = NEW.hash_group_id;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And create function for getting actual group id:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_hash_group;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION get_hash_group(id INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  IF (id IS NULL) THEN
    INSERT INTO `hash_group` (`group_name`) 
    VALUES (md5(now())); -- replace to you hash
    RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
  END IF;

  RETURN id;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Scenario:

Initial fill:

```
INSERT INTO `hash_group` (id, group_name) VALUES 
(1, 'test1'),
(2, 'test2'),
(3, 'test3');

INSERT INTO `hashes` (hash, hash_group_id) VALUES
('hash11', 1),
('hash12', 1),
('hash13', 1),
('hash2', 2),
('hash3', 3);

INSERT INTO `emails` (hash_group_id, group_id, email)
VALUES
(1, 'g1', 'example1@'),
(2, 'g1', 'example2@'),
(3, 'g1', 'example2@');
```

Updating of `hash_group` scenario:

```
START TRANSACTION;

-- Get @min_group_id - minimum group id (we will leave this id and delete other)

SELECT MIN(hash_group_id) INTO @min_group_id
FROM hashes 
WHERE hash IN ('hash11', 'hash12', 'hash2', 'hash15');

-- Replace other group ids in email table to @min_group_id

UPDATE `emails` 
SET `hash_group_id` = @min_group_id
WHERE `hash_group_id` IN (
  SELECT hash_group_id
  FROM hashes 
  WHERE @min_group_id IS NOT NULL
  AND hash IN ('hash11', 'hash12', 'hash2', 'hash15')
  -- Update only if we are gluy several hash_groups
  AND `hash_group_id` > @min_group_id
);

-- Delete other hash_groups and leave only group with @min_group_id

DELETE FROM `hash_group` WHERE `id` IN (
  SELECT hash_group_id
  FROM hashes 
  WHERE @min_group_id IS NOT NULL
  AND hash IN ('hash11', 'hash12', 'hash2', 'hash15')
  -- Delete only if we are gluy several hash_groups
  AND `hash_group_id` > @min_group_id
);

-- @group_id = existing hash_group.id or create new if @min_group_id is null (all inserted hashes are new)

SELECT get_hash_group(@min_group_id) INTO @group_id;

-- Now we can insert new hashes.

INSERT INTO `hashes` (hash, hash_group_id) VALUES
('hash11', @group_id),
('hash12', @group_id),
('hash2', @group_id),
('hash15', @group_id)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE repeat_count = repeat_count + 1;


COMMIT;
```

Comment: I don't think this method would work. For instance, if I added into `hashes` the values `hash11` and `hash3` at the same time, given what's already there, what would be the output? I can explain the question better to you on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117832/on-update-ignore-cascade

Comment: You can use `UPDATE .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE repeat_count=repeat_count+1` and create trigger on update `hashes` for this purpose. You can update `hash_group.group_name` from trigger.

Comment: Can you show an example of this trigger? I'm having a hard time picturing the workflow

Comment: Also, I realized I omitted the unique key in my `CREATE TABLE code` for emails. I apologize because it most likely impacts your answer.

Comment: @Charlie, I updated answer to support situation when several groups are stick together.

Comment: can we talk more about this on chat?

Comment: Yes. I'm in chat now. Advantages of this approach are: normlized database structure and control of data entry with foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

I maybe wrong but I think you mis-named the `id` field in `hashes`.

I think you should rename the `id` field in `hashes` to something like `group_id`, then have a `AUTO_INCREMENT` field called `id` that should also be PRIMARY in `hashes` that the `id` in `emails` refers to this field instead. When you want to update and relate all the hashes together, you update the `group_id` field instead of `id`, and `id` remains unique across the table.

This way you can avoid the cascade problem, also you will always know the original hash that the email was referring to.
Sure, if you want to fetch all the hashes related to an email (old and the new) you must exectue and extra query, but I think it solves all your problems.

Edit:
you can use a trigger to do this

The trigger goes like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `update_hash_id` AFTER UPDATE ON `hashes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `emails` SET `id` = NEW.id WHERE `id` = OLD.id;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and you must remove the foreign key relation too.

Comment: Then there will still be duplicate emails relating back to the same `id`. Sure, the `group_id` makes it "unique," but that's what I'm doing in my current implementation. I just realized I forgot a unique key in the emails table. As you can see, what I'm doing now is more or less exactly what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Charlie I know that a trigger solves your problem while maintaining your original structure. I update the answer to write the trigger

Comment: I'm failing to see how this implementation is different than the one I currently have though. It just seems like another way to do the same thing, right?

Comment: Yes it is but the difference is that when it's not using foreign keys and the id in emails is not unique, it won't result duplicate error.

Comment: I mean currently it does't produce a duplicate error either, it only does so if I  omit `group_id` from the `unique` key in `emails`, which is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an extra integer column to each of the child tables would avoid this problem altogether by using it as a primary key.  The key never changes because it isn't a reference to anything else.

Using composite keys as primary keys is generally something that you want to avoid.  And considering that this key combination is not always unique, I would definitely say you need a dedicated primary key in all of your child tables with this problem.

You can even auto increment it so you aren't manually assigning it every time.  For example..

```
Create Table exampleTable
(   
    trueID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 varChar(50)
    PRIMARY KEY(trueID)
)
```

Then, when two of the rows in a child table are set with identical values (for whatever reason), the primary key stays unique, preventing any conflicts in the Database that could arise.